# Einstein's spacetime thought doubt

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, curvature, visualization

[image]

In the animation of this image you can see spacetime is constantly going towards the earth's center of mass, and when a layer of spacetime reaches to the earth's center of mass another layer of spacetime generates instantly. It means spacetime regenerates it i.e spacetime is infinite. But infinity doesn't exist in this limited universe. So what is wrong here?

Comment: https://xkcd.com/895/

Answer (score 1):

> when a layer of spacetime reaches to the earth's center of mass another layer of spacetime generates instantly. ... So what is wrong here?

This is just part of the animation. There is nothing in either the physics or in the math that corresponds to the “layers” you are seeing. It is just a small clip of an animation that is on a loop. The layer is simply what you see when the loop fades back to the beginning.

Answer (score -3):

Many attempts have been made to model SpaceTime and the warping of SpaceTime as portrayed in relativity. Perhaps the most famous is the bowling ball in a trampoline model. And the model you have shown is just another one. All of these have serious flaws.

I find it best to look at gravity as behaving exactly like a low pressure system. That could be a low pressure system in the weather, where the wind is drawn in towards the center of the low. The air of the wind is drawn in towards the center by the difference in air pressure on the inside of the low compared to the outside of the low. Likewise an object falls to the ground because of the difference in pressure, that could be the pressure of time, below and above the falling object. There are many similarities between gravity and a low pressure system such as the frame dragging of the wind and the fujiwara effect between the merger of two hurricanes compared to the merger of two galaxies. So don't give too much credence to the diagram you're looking at. It is simply one model.

Comment: This is a good analogy except remember there’s no such thing as suction. It is a higher pressure pushing in.

Comment: You gave me the example of low pressure system. But the low pressure system doesn't dedcribes anything infinite. But the model is. So, can I say that the model is wrong?

Comment: The air pressure model is simply an analogy. It would become infinite if the air was completely frictionless, or if the air went on forever. It is just a better model to envision gravity then the model you were looking at. I am sure that this model also has flaws. But I find it better than any of the other models I've seen.

Comment: Air is limited. So limited air can't infinitely go towards one area.

Comment: As I said above, this is just a model. Don't try to make it perfect because it won't become perfect.

Comment: You are right. I am leaving this matter now.